# Verify "suppressUnattendedReboot" option of Install4j

Tags: install4j

I am implementing silent upgrade using "Updater without version check" of install4j. After finishing silent upgrade I dont want to reboot machine in any scenario. 
So I am passing parameter "-Dinstall4j.suppressUnattendedReboot=true" via ""Set installer arguments" action. Now I want to test whether is working or not? Is there any way to verify this parameter is passed to installer? And force reboot in between update and check this parameter actually suppressed reboot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way to verify this parameter is passed to installer?

In a "Run script" action, you can check

```
Boolean.getBoolean("install4j.suppressUnattendedReboot")
```

> and check this parameter actually suppressed reboot?

For testing, you can force the installer to reboot by adding the "Reboot computer" action. The `-Dinstall4j.suppressUnattendedReboot=true` argument will then prevent the reboot from happening.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: To check suppress reboot I want to somehow force reboot without prompt  during installation and then want to check whether "suppressUnattendedReboot" has suppressed this reboot or not?

Comment: Hi Ingo,                                                                                                             I am getting null when I call Boolean.getBoolean("install4j.suppressUnattendedReboot") in Run Script action which I am calling before "Install files". Earlier  I passed "-Dinstall4j.suppressUnattendedReboot=true" from "Set installer arguments". But  Boolean.getBoolean(..) given me null. Then I passed "-Dinstall4j.suppressUnattendedReboot=true" from ApplicationLauncher.launchApplicationInProcess(...). Still I am getting null. Is there any thing wrong in my code?

Comment: Try to pass -J-Dinstall4j.suppressUnattendedReboot=true to the installer. Does that make any difference?

Comment: I will check and let you know.

Comment: "-J-Dinstall4j.suppressUnattendedReboot=true" also failed. I passed this parameter from ApplicationLauncher.launchApplicationInProcess(...) and "Set installer arguments". Machine got rebooted and  Boolean.getBoolean("install4j.suppressUnattendedReboot") returned null. I am using Install4j 5.1.15.

Comment: Strange. What if you add -Dinstall4j.suppressUnattendedReboot=true to the "VM parameters" property of the installer under Installer->Screens & Actions?

Comment: I added "-Dinstall4j.suppressUnattendedReboot=true" in VM parameters of "Install" and "Updater without version check". Boolean.getBoolean(...) returns true only if I upgrade manually by running installer. When I start auto update by calling ApplicationLauncher.launchApplicationInProcess(...) I get false. I added   "suppressUnattendedReboot" in arguments of launchApplicationInProcess(...). Is there any issue in ApplicationLauncher.launchApplicationInProcess(...) API.

Comment: Boolean.getBoolean actually cannot return null, it returns a primitive boolean. Can you check System.getProperty("install4j.suppressUnattendedReboot") for the actual value of the system property?

Comment: Sorry Boolean.getBoolean() returned false not null.

Comment: The mechanism of passing system properties definitely works for me. Can you check System.getProperty("install4j.suppressUnattendedReboot") or use a tool like jconsole to look at the system properties?

Comment: I will do that. But main issue is that machine gets rebooted !!. I want to stop this reboot. And when I run manual upgrade I got true. But for auto update I am getting false.

Comment: You can also add a "Run script" action and call System.setProperty("install4j.suppressUnattendedReboot", "true);

Comment: Finally this worked :).  Thanks lot for your help !!. Actually I was new in Java and Install4j. That's why I struggled lot. Once again thanks for your help.